# Generate unique value during Merge Into

Tags: sql

I have a Merge Into statement that calls a UDF to generate a unique value based on fields passed into the Merge statement. Basically I have a table of names, when I merge into a table of URLs. The function makes the names URL-friendly, and makes sure they are unique.

The problem is that the UDF doesn't detect the conflicting URLs if they are inserted by the merge statement. If the URL is in there before the merge starts, it detects it fine and adds the suffix.

So if I have 2 names, both 'John Doe', it creates 2 'JohnDoe' URLs in the merge. If there's already a 'JohnDoe' URL, it creates 2 'JohnDoe1' URLs.

Is there any way to get the UDF to look at the just-updated table for duplicates, rather than what the table was when the Merge Into started?

Merge Into statement:

```
MERGE INTO url_table
USING name_table
ON name_key= url_key
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT ( url_value )
VALUES (dbo.get_unique_url ( name_value));
```

get_unique_url UDF:

```
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR ( 50 ) = @name_value
--Remove non-alpha characters
DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR ( 50 ) = '%[^a-z]%'
WHILE PATINDEX ( @KeepValues , @url ) > 0
SET @url = STUFF ( @url , PATINDEX ( @KeepValues , @url ), 1 , '' )

DECLARE @suffix INT= 1
WHILE EXISTS( SELECT url_value FROM url_table ( NOLOCK ) WHERE url_value = @url )
BEGIN
SET @url = @url + CONVERT ( NVARCHAR ( 5 ), @suffix )
END

-- Return the good URL
RETURN @url
```

*Edited to fix code display*

Comment: Use temporary table to insert values using UDF and then merge from that temporary table into target one without use of UDF

Comment: Sorry, it didn't like my copy/paste. Code display should be better now

Comment: @DavidJashi - I'm not sure what you mean by this. Would the temp table not suffer from the same problem, i.e. when it starts, it has no URLs, so everything comes back as not a dupe?

Comment: @Drew Your problem is, that table, on which UDF works on, is mutating, right? So, to avoid this you should first insert UDF-generated values in **another** table, and then merge this another table with original one.